# undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0000559c6e193560>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each

I'm trying to show the features of certain storage that the user selects from a form, but when trying to display the show view, I get

```
undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0000559c6e193560>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @storage.features.each do |feature| %>
  <div>
    <%= feature %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If I use `<%= @storage.features %>` the outcome is an array with the selected features, like this: `["Pet Free", "Smoke Detector", "Climate Controlled", "Easy Access"]`. But I would like to show every feature separately, hence, I was trying to use `.each`

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(Storage.new) do |f| %>
[...]
  <% FeaturesData::Features.each do |feature| %>
    <div>
      <%= f.check_box :features, { multiple: true }, feature, nil %>
      <%= f.label feature %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.button :submit, 'Create Post'%>
<% end %>
```

**app/models/concerns/features_data.rb**

```rb
module FeaturesData
  Features = [
    "Pet Free",
    "Security Camera",
    "Smoke Detector",
    "Climate Controlled",
    "Locked Area",
    "Easy Access",
    "Independent Space"
  ]
end
```

**storages_controller.rb**

```
def storage_params
  params.require(:storage).permit(
    :title,
    :description,
    :address,
    :storage_type,
    :city,
    :country,
    :latitude,
    :longitude,
    :price,
    :meters,
    :user_id,
    features: [],
    photos: []
  )
end
```

Comment: whats the output of ```@storage.features``` ?

Comment: can you please add your controller code, where `@storage` is initialized?

Comment: Can you check the type of `@storage.features` by `@storage.features.class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running `@storage.features.each` returns `undefined method 'each' for #<String:0x0000559c6e193560>` error this means that `@storage.features` is a string, not an array. You are saying that calling `<%= @storage.features %>` returns an array but I suspect it's probably a string that looks like an array: `'["Pet Free", "Smoke Detector", "Climate Controlled", "Easy Access"]'`.

Have you perhaps forgotten to instruct Rails to [serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) your features by adding `serialize :features` in your storage.rb model file?

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly by adding serialize :features to the Storage model